# custom CMD command for running python script with input parameter

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd

I want to create a custom cmd command that will open a python script and also have a input parameter.

example:
C:\Users\myName> create newFolder

so create is for opening the python script (create.py)
and the parameter is for making a new folder with the same name.

kinda like this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Y8Ppin12r4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a .bat file with the following contents.  Assume anything in bold should be replaced by you.

**path\to\Python** **Path\to\Script**

And of course, you'd need to set up an argument parser in your script. Here's an example one:

```py
from argparse import ArgumentParser() as parser
parser.add_argument("example-argument", type=int, help="A number between 1 and 10."
args = parser.parse_args()
Number = args.example-argument
if Number < 1:
    print("Try a higher number.")
elif Number > 10:
    print("Try a lower number.")
else:
    print(Number)
```

Then put that in a directory wherever you want. Call the directory something like CommandScripts, for example. Then change your PATH environment variable to check that directory, and you can use your new command from anywhere on your system.

Comment: If that's `.bat` then you rather want `path\to\python path\to\script`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I always forget those pesky backslashes. Thanks!

Comment: both answers are probably right but i think i just gonna do it in python since am not 
experience enough with batch. ty anyway.

Comment: Okay. You know the batch file does only have to be one line though, right?

Answer (score 0):

your .bat command can look like this

> python your_python_file.py your_arguments

and your python file itself

```
import sys
for arg in sys.argv:
    print(arg)
```

You may notice that first arg is your file name itself.

Comment: both answers are probably right but i think i just gonna do it in python since am not 
experience enough with batch. ty anyway.